Form Repeater destroy Select2 dropdown UI
I'm trying to reinitialize Select2 for dynamically added repeater items in my form. The Select2 plugin works fine on page load, but when I add a new repeater item, the Select2 dropdown UI isn't reinitialized properly. Its more of a UI problem but the dropdown works just fine.

Here’s what I've been doing:
<div id="repeaterItems">
    <div class="repeater-item">
         <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                  <label class="control-label">Action Plan</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="action[]" placeholder="Enter action plan.." required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                <label class="control-label">Implementer</label>
                <select class="select2 form-control d-inline w-50" multiple="multiple" name="department[][]" style="width: 100%">
                 <option disabled value="">-- Please Choose --</option>
                 @foreach ($depts as $dept)
                       <option value="{{ $dept->dp_code }}">{{ $dept->dp_name }}</option>
                 @endforeach
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md mt-auto mb-3">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger removeButton"><span class="mdi mdi-close-circle-outline"></span></button>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md mb-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="addButton"><span class="mdi mdi-plus-circle-outline"></span>&nbsp;Add Plan</button>
</div>

And here's the script where I did try to reinitialize Select2 for the newly cloned .select2 element:
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2').select2({
            placeholder: "-- Choose Department --",
            allowClear: true
        });
        
        $('#addButton').click(function() {
            var newItem = $('#repeaterItems .repeater-item:first').clone();
            newItem.find('input').val('');
            newItem.find('.removeButton').show();
            $('#repeaterItems').append(newItem);

            newItem.find('.select2-container').remove();
            newItem.find('.select2').select2({
                placeholder: "-- Choose Department --",
                allowClear: true
            });
        });

        $('#repeaterItems').on('click', '.removeButton', function() {
            $(this).closest('.repeater-item').remove();
        });
    });
</script>


You might need to re-initialize select2 for the new row of repeater like this:
show: function () {
 $('.select2-container').remove();
 $('.select2').select2();
 $(this).slideDown();
},


this doesnt solve the dropdown ui issue.
